# bootstrap-input-spinner - prevent propagation when syncing two spinners

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use bootstrap-input-spinner to make synchronised min/max spinners. When the min is set to greater than the max the max should increment to be one more than the min and vice-versa.

The problem is that they don't seem to sync properly on the way up but weirdly they do on the way down.

```
<input type="number" value="0" id="add_question_min_number" name="add_question_min_number">
                <input type="number" value="10" id="add_question_max_number" name="add_question_max_number">
                <script>

                    $(document).on("input", '#add_question_min_number', function(event) {
                        
                       
                        if ($("#add_question_max_number").val() <= $(this).val()) {
                            $("#add_question_max_number").val($(this).val() + 1);
                        }

                    
                    })
                    $(document).on("input", '#add_question_max_number', function(event) {
                        
 
                            if ($("#add_question_min_number").val() >= $(event.target).val()) {
                            $("#add_question_min_number").val($(event.target).val() - 1);
                        }

                    })
</script>
```

I have a feeling this might be a propagation issue, but as I write, it works when you decrease the max but not when you increase the min.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript

The value of `$("#add_question_max_number").val()` and `$(this).val()` is string. This results in the error you get.

For example:

The value of `$(this).val()` is `"10"`

When set `$("#add_question_max_number").val($(this).val() + 1);` =>`$("#add_question_max_number").val("10" + 1);`

Result: `$("#add_question_max_number").val("101");`

To fix it you just need to convert them to numeric values like this:

```
const min = parseInt($(this).val())
const max = parseInt($("#add_question_max_number").val())
```

Final code in here:

```
$(document).on("input", '#add_question_min_number', function(event) {
    const min = parseInt($(this).val())
    const max = parseInt($("#add_question_max_number").val())
    if (max <= min) {
        $("#add_question_max_number").val(min + 1);
    }
})
$(document).on("input", '#add_question_max_number', function(event) {
    const min = parseInt($("#add_question_min_number").val())
    const max = parseInt($(this).val())
    if (min >= max) {
        $("#add_question_min_number").val(max - 1);
    }
})
```